# Scraping Data from a website: issues with tags identification

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to build a dataframe with Date, Title and Content of a website.
To scrape this information, I am doing as follows:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd


def main(req, num):
    r = req.get("http://www.lavocedellevoci.it/category/inchieste/page/{}/".format(num))
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
    for tag in soup.select(".contents"):
        print(tag.select_one(".homepage_post_title auto-height td").text)
        print(tag.select_one(".homepage_post-date td-module-date a").text)
        print(tag.find_next(class_="col-sm-8 nopadding").text.strip())
    
    return tag.select_one(".homepage_post_title auto-height homepage_post-date td-module-date a").text,text, tag.find_next(class_="col-sm-8 nopadding").text.strip()
```

It seems there is a problem with tags nothing has been printed. If you could tell me what it is wrong, I would appreciate it.

Comment: You seem to be selecting the wrong elements. For example, your first selector should be: `soup.select(".contents > div > article")`. After that, it's just iterating through the tags and picking the tag elements you are interested in

Comment: thanks recent advances. Are the tags I used also wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following grabs each investigation, converts dates into actual dates and then visits each article page to get the associated text. It uses `Session` for the efficiency of tcp re-use.

In your original script the use of `.contents` matches a single parent node rather than the child `articles`. Then later you neglect to join the multi-value class in the css selector e.g. `.homepage_post_title auto-height td` should be `.homepage_post_title.auto-height td`, where the separate class values are joined by "." in order to not be seen as a `type` selector. It is faster, and generally more robust, to pick a single, stable looking, class from the multi-values and use that, as shown below.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import pandas as pd
import datetime

def get_date(date_string):
    date_parts = date_string.split(' ')
    article_date = '-'.join([date_parts[-1], month_numbers[date_parts[1].lower()], date_parts[0].zfill(2)])
    d = datetime.datetime.strptime(article_date, "%Y-%m-%d").date()
    return d

month_numbers =  { 'gennaio' : '01',
                    'febbraio' : '02',
                    'marzo' : '03',
                    'aprile' : '04',
                    'maggio' : '05',
                    'giugno' : '06',
                    'luglio' : '07',
                    'agosto' : '08',
                    'settembre' : '09',
                    'ottobre' : '10',
                    'novembre' : '11',
                    'dicembre' : '12',
        }

def main(page):
    
    results = []

    with requests.Session() as s:

        soup =  bs(s.get(f'http://www.lavocedellevoci.it/category/inchieste/page/{page}').content, 'lxml')

        for article in soup.select('article'):  #soup.select('article:has(a:contains("Inchieste"))') if need to be more restrictive in future
            title = article.select_one('h1').text
            date = get_date(article.select_one('.homepage_post-date').text)
            link = article.select_one('.read-more')['href']
            soup2 =  bs(s.get(link).content, 'lxml')
            text = '\n'.join([i.text for i in soup2.select('article p:not([class])')])
            results.append([title, date, text])

        df = pd.DataFrame(results, columns = ['Title', 'Date', 'Content'])
        print(df)
        
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main(1)
```

---

Read more about css selectors here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors

---

You could introduce a `while` loop to get all pages, which stops when the class `.next`, associated with `Successivi`, is no longer present, or stop after `n` pages:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import pandas as pd
import datetime

def get_date(date_string):
    date_parts = date_string.split(' ')
    article_date = '-'.join([date_parts[-1], month_numbers[date_parts[1].lower()], date_parts[0].zfill(2)])
    d = datetime.datetime.strptime(article_date, "%Y-%m-%d").date()
    return d

month_numbers =  { 'gennaio' : '01',
                    'febbraio' : '02',
                    'marzo' : '03',
                    'aprile' : '04',
                    'maggio' : '05',
                    'giugno' : '06',
                    'luglio' : '07',
                    'agosto' : '08',
                    'settembre' : '09',
                    'ottobre' : '10',
                    'novembre' : '11',
                    'dicembre' : '12',
        }

next_page = True
final = pd.DataFrame()

def main(page):
    global final
    global next_page
    results = []

    with requests.Session() as s:

        soup =  bs(s.get(f'http://www.lavocedellevoci.it/category/inchieste/page/{page}').content, 'lxml')
    
        for article in soup.select('article'):  #soup.select('article:has(a:contains("Inchieste"))') if need to be more restrictive in future
            title = article.select_one('h1').text
            date = get_date(article.select_one('.homepage_post-date').text)
            link = article.select_one('.read-more')['href']
            soup2 =  bs(s.get(link).content, 'lxml')
            text = '\n'.join([i.text for i in soup2.select('article p:not([class])')])
            results.append([title, date, text])

        df = pd.DataFrame(results, columns = ['Title', 'Date', 'Content'])
        
        if df.empty:
            final = df
        else:
            final = pd.concat([final, df], sort = False)
        
        next_page = soup.select_one('.next') is not None
        
if __name__ == '__main__':
    page = 1

    while next_page: # page < 3: 
        main(page)
        page+=1
        
    final = final.sort_values('Date').reset_index()
    print(final)
```

Answer (score 0):

So, my solution:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

def main(num):
    dict_ = {
        'date': [],
        'title': [],
        'content': []
    }
    r = requests.get(f"http://www.lavocedellevoci.it/category/inchieste/page/{num}/")
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text)
    for article in soup.select('article.border_top'):
        dict_['date'].append(article.select_one('span.homepage_post-date').text)
        dict_['title'].append(article.select_one('h1.homepage_post_title').text)
        dict_['content'].append(article.select_one('p').text)

    return pd.DataFrame(dict_)
```

Comment: Hi Danil Pudovkin. I think the right one should be `contents`. It should contain the first page. Then I should scroll the other pages. However the problem seems to be related to the tags. It would be ok if you could try with only one page (if it is too complicated for the first two).

Comment: Hi, The_Ark. I wrote the solution. It works for me. Please, check that. Oh, I just didn't see the date in the content. I think you can remove it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```py
r = requests.get("http://www.lavocedellevoci.it/category/inchieste/page/3/")
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
for tag in soup.select(".contents > div > article"):
    print(tag.select_one("h1.homepage_post_title").string)
    print(tag.select_one("span.homepage_post-date").string)
    print(tag.select_one("a.read-more").parent.contents[0])
```